# Errno::EACCES in Welcome#index

Tags: mysql, css, ruby-on-rails, passenger

I'm  getting this error after creating a test app on Rails 4.1.5 , currently running on a test enviroment configured with apache and mysql, using passenger, on Fedora 21 so far I´ve tried everything regarding ownership and permissions, but it is still not working.

Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /var/www/html/blog/tmp
  (in /var/www/html/blog/app/assets/stylesheets/welcome.css.scss)

Extracted source (around line #5):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Blog</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks- 
track' => true %> 
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' =>   
true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

Rails.root: /var/www/html/blog

Comment: Check permissions and owners use `namei -lm <absolute path to file or directory>`.

Comment: dr-xr-xr-x root   root /
drwxr-xr-x root   root var
drwxrwxrwx root   root www
drwxrwxrwx root   root html
drwxrwxrwx apache root blog